# Random Variables Study Example

Tags: self-study, random-variable, independence

I was studying random processes and couldn't solve this? Could you help?

"Let x and y be zero-mean, jointly Gaussian random variables. Assuming that Var(**x**)= $\sigma_x^2$and Var(**y**)= $\sigma_y^2$, find a scalar a in terms of variance of x and and $r_{xy}$ such that **x**-a**y** and **y** are independent  random variables?"

I don't understand this: if **x** and **y** are independent then $f_x(x)f_y(y)=f_{xy}(xy)$ but how can I place **x**-a**y**?

Comment: The variables x and are jointly Gaussian so they can be correlated and in fact they have correlation $r_xy$. So find the a that makes them independent. As a hint: In addition to finding **a** that makes the product of the marginal densities the joint density you can just pick **a** to make them uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know (and use) two facts about *jointly* Gaussian random variables.

1. If $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* Gaussian random variables, then,
   for all choices of real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$,and $\delta$, so also are $\alpha X + \beta Y$ and $\gamma X + \delta Y$  *jointly* Gaussian random variables.
2. *Jointly* Gaussian random variables are independent if and only if they are *uncorrelated* random variables, or, equivalently, if they have zero covariance.

So, what can you say about the joint distribution of $X-aY$ and $Y$ given that $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* Gaussian random variables?  Regardless of the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, do you know (or can you figure out) how to calculate $\operatorname{cov}(X-aY, Y)$, the covariance of
$X-aY$ and $Y$, in terms of $\sigma_X^2, \sigma_Y^2$ and
$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$?  Is there a value of $a$ for which
$\operatorname{cov}(X-aY, Y)$ has value $0$?